# Remove .html, .php, .aspx , etc from the URL in static sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a situation that i have to show the html pages without using their extension

such as about us page is currently named `about-us.html`, i want to show it only `about-us`

Comment: you can map dynamic urls in your server side code

Comment: try reading this : [HTML5: Changing the browser-URL without refreshing page](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/). See if will help you.

Answer (score 3):

you should use urlRewriting to remove file extension 
if you use apache then

[Apache Link](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

for IIS

[IIS Link](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the URL. Please check the following link:      **[URL rewriting with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)**